# Is there a function for finding the Nth weekday of the month for a given date in python?

Tags: python, datetime

Lets say I have the date 12/8/2020. Is there a function that would output that it was the 2nd Tuesday of December?

Additionally, I would like a way to do the reverse. Input the 2nd Tuesday of December in 2020 and it would output 12/8/2020.

Comment: What if someone asks for the 6th Tuesday of December?

Comment: Assume no one will do that haha. I have nice friends

Answer (score 1):

the `datetime` module (or the friendly pandas wrapped version) has most of the functionality you need.  You can use `humanize` (or write your own) function to convert number to ordinality:

```
import pandas as pd
import humanize
def day_in_month(date_str):

    dt = pd.to_datetime(date_str)
    dow = dt.day_name()
    dow_ord = 1 + (dt.day - 1)//7
    dow_ord_str = humanize.ordinal(dow_ord)
    month = dt.month_name()
    year = dt.year
    output = f"{dow_ord_str} {dow} of {month} in {year}" 
    return output

date_str = "12/8/2020"
day_in_month(date_str)
```

output:

```
'2nd Tuesday of December in 2020'
```

Comment: There is an error in `dow_ord = 1 + dt.day // 7` and I can't explain it well, but `dow_ord = math.ceil(dt.day / 7)` will give correct result. (Need to import math) The way it stands now, it increments the ordinal once early.

Comment: That is, it will incorrectly say `2nd` Monday on Dec 7. when it should say `1st` Monday. for Dec 7 (2020) (The same happens on 14,21 and 28)

Comment: OK, I was working through it myself. I didn't know about the humanize package - good to see it.